# Building error with IJulia

Tags: julia, zeromq, ijulia-notebook

I used to use Julia in Jupyter notebook. I uninstalled yesterday the `.julia` directory because of other issues and after `Pkg.add(IJulia)` Im getting a building error related to `ZMQ`. the full error is below.

```
julia> Pkg.build("ZMQ")
INFO: Building Homebrew
Already up-to-date.
INFO: Building ZMQ
Warning: staticfloat/juliatranslated/zeromq32-3.2.5 already installed, it's just not linked.
Error: Formulae found in multiple taps: 
 * staticfloat/juliadeps/zeromq32
 * staticfloat/juliatranslated/zeromq32

Please use the fully-qualified name e.g. staticfloat/juliadeps/zeromq32 to refer the formula.
=================================[ ERROR: ZMQ ]=================================

LoadError: failed process: Process(`/Users/pacagal/.julia/v0.5/Homebrew/deps/usr/bin/brew link staticfloat/juliatranslated/zeromq32 --force`, ProcessExited(1)) [1]
while loading /Users/pacagal/.julia/v0.5/ZMQ/deps/build.jl, in expression starting on line 35

================================================================================

================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]================================

WARNING: ZMQ had build errors.

 - packages with build errors remain installed in /Users/pacagal/.julia/v0.5
 - build the package(s) and all dependencies with `Pkg.build("ZMQ")`
 - build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script

================================================================================
```

I have also run the `build.jl` file but I am getting an error too.

Comment: I know I've dealt with this error several times before
But I can't recall how.
Can you post the versions of everything (julia and the packages)

Comment: These are the required packages I have installed now: 
`julia> Pkg.status()
5 required packages:
 - Atom                          0.5.9
 - DifferentialEquations         1.8.0
 - IJulia                        1.4.1
 - Juno                          0.2.7
 - Plots                         0.10.3
108 additional packages:
`@LyndonWhite

NOTE: I have had this same problem in you different computers, both with Mac OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue this morning. In the terminal I ran `brew install zmq` and that resolved the issue.

I still had to run `julia>Pkg.build("Nettle")` after installing zmq and after that IJulia is running fine.